# Adding images a product created from a module in prestashop

Tags: php, module, prestashop

I am using prestashop version 1.4.4 and I want creating a module for creating a product with pictures. I am getting the fields from user using form than I try to create a product using product class like

$product = new Product();
$product->price = 10;
...
$product->add();

product created succesfully but 
after this how can add product images using Image class
I am able to save image in temporary file on server but how can
bing to the product?
any help

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look in admin_folder/tabs/AdminProducts.php, around line 434 you have an exemple. Or search /* Product images management */ in the same file

Regards